# How can I programmatically click a button on a custom MS Office Access Ribbon?

Tags: c#, automation, ms-access-2010

I'm looking for some guidance here, if not an example of how to accomplish what I am looking to do in C-Sharp(C#).

There is a particular button on a MS Access Ribbon that I would like to click. The MS Access window has a custom UI and custom buttons in different groups. When the button in the first group is clicked, it then opens a childform window. I need to automate that particular step and have my C# application programmatically open that child form by clicking the button or any other means to get it open.

I attempted to do this with the SendKeys and FindWindow functions, but this prove to be rather faulty, because the ALT id's kept changing in MS Access and the SendKeys would stop working.

I've tried searching for articles that would help me with this issue, but all I came across are tutorials on how to make a custom add-in for MS ribbon (I do not want this).

There might be a better way to do this and any help with it is greatly appreciated!

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string strClassName, int nptWindowName);

[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

Public Void SendTest()
{
IntPtr WinHandle = FindWindow("OMain", 0); // OMain = Window Class --found window by class

 if (WinHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Program is not running or could not be detected.");
     return;
 }

SetForegroundWindow(WinHandle);
SendKeys.SendWait("%"); // ALT
SendKeys.SendWait("Y1"); // Y1
SendKeys.SendWait("Y1"); //Y1
}
```